# Sybase database - Issue running stored proc

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, sybase

I am trying to run a stored proc "dbname..rr_deck_type_wrap_proc" through SQLDeveloper worksheet using the following code:

```
declare @return int, @message varchar(255)      
exec @return =  DBname..rr_deck_type_wrap_proc 
                          @new_id = '123456789',
                          @remarks = 'Test',
                      @error_cd = @message output
select @return "@return", @message "@message"
```

However, I always get the message:

> Error report - Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 22 '='
>   character expected.

This code works perfectly fine when run through another software/interface. It is probably a syntax issue with SQLDeveloper, tried different things but nothing worked. Can someone suggest anything. Thank you!

Comment: The error message indicates that the JDBC driver tries to do some escaping. But that can't be disabled in SQL Developer. See also this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1009263 (and this https://community.oracle.com/thread/3981212 for an insight on how Oracle cares about standards)

Comment: Thank you for the response and links! Looks like in my situation it is best to use some other tool.

Answer (score 1):

You're using 'Oracle SQL Developer' - the keyword there, being 'Oracle.'

You're connected to a SAP Sybase database. Which is perfectly fine. We provide this connectivity support for one reason, and one reason only:

To allow you to migrate it to Oracle Database.

It is NOT a T-SQL IDE. It does not provide any support really for running, debugging, playing with T-SQL.

If you have ANSI-SQL, then our parser will probably be OK with it.

If you need/want a hack, and are desperate to make your code go, then you can provide a hint to our parser, to just let the code go through to the driver, and hope it works.

An example:

```
/sqldev:query*/sp_help;
```

You could also try adding this

```
/*sqldev:stmt*/
```

This advice applies to MySQL, DB2, SQL Server, Teradata, or any other 3rd party JDBC driver we allow you to use in SQL Developer. It's there to help you move your schema and application code over into an Oracle Database.

Comment: At least for a java developer using MacOS it still seems to be one of the best free tools for running queries on SQL Server despite the hacks (!)